# How do you access multiple OpenCV confidence values for any given image?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to build a program that can use the OpenCV Face Recogniser to identify which of the sample faces in a trained model is most similar to the target face from a webcam stream. I am unsuccessfully trying to find a way of accessing the confidence values of all the faces, however the only documentation I can find is from [here.](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html#ac0bd26e07264757a5b1e7909897e2939)

From what I can see, that only returns the confidence of the final face prediction as opposed to all of them. I looked into the predictCollector, but couldn't figure out the rather minimal documentation. From what I could garner, it didn't seem suitable anyway...

What I would like is some sort of list structure that I can examine and use to identify some of the highest and lowest confidence values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the function directly below the one you linked?

Comment: Yes, it relies on the predictCollector which I am struggling to understand as the documentation is minimal as I said...

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV 3.1.0 which you linked to you can use several different `predictCollectors`, you can find a list of them [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d98/predict__collector_8hpp.html#gsc.tab=0).

The one you need is the [`TopNPredictCollector`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/d36/classcv_1_1face_1_1TopNPredictCollector.html#gsc.tab=0):

> Detailed Description
>
> Collects top N most close predictions.

As you can see the Detailed Descripton is currently not very ... detailed.
If you need to know more your best chance is to look directly at the source which can be found [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/face/src).